# What this is, and how can it be put into Sibelius?

Tags: theory, piano, notation, beats, sibelius

[image: 4/4 time signature]

If you look at the bass staff, there is one more 16th note than there should be on a 4/4 time signature. Can someone explain this to me? And what is the number of top of the barline?

Comment: There are no sixteenth notes at all.

Answer (score 10):

The three eighth notes (not 16th notes) with the "3" above the beam are a "triplet": three notes in the space of one beat. There are exactly four beats in the measure.

---

For instructions on how to enter triplets in Sibelius, see the Sibelius manual entry ["Tuplets - how to create"](https://avid.secure.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/How_To/en360509).